# how to store the data into 2 tables in liferay service builder?

Tags: liferay

i have already created one portlet name is course-portlet. i have created the add.jsp for storing the course in to the database using service layer. now my requirement is i need to store the course details in two tables course,course_user. in course table column values are
cid,cname,sdate,sid. for this table i have created service builder. now my requirement is i have to create the another class in service layer which need to store the values in the table course_user cuid,cid,uid.is it possible with  existing service layer? if possible how ? i have already created the methods addcourse() editcouse() and deletecourse() methods?

Answer (score 0):

To add new entity using service builder

```
<entity name="Course_User" local-service="true"
        remote-service="false">
        <column name="cuid" type="long" primary="true"></column>
        <column name="cid" type="Course" entity="Course" mapping-key="cid"></column>

        <finder name="Cid" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="cid" />
        </finder>

        // finder method according to your need
    </entity>
```

HTH

Comment: cid is primary key in course table. if i delete the cid in course table, the related cid in course_user will be delete with the above code?